# confusion with converting epoch time to local time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have epoch time which I need to convert to local time (US/Pacific). I get the following results using `pandas to_datetime()` function and `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`.

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1554782410.0370002)
Out[704]: datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 8, 21, 0, 10, 37000)

pd.to_datetime(1554782410.0370002, unit='s')
Out[705]: Timestamp('2019-04-09 04:00:10.037000179')
```

Note that the time difference is 7:00 hrs between the two output. How do I reconcile the two?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could always subtract 7 hours manually using pd.Timedelta()

Comment: what outcome are you looking for?  "Reconcile" isn't very specific

Comment: add timezone to reconcile the two. `pd.to_datetime(1554782410.0370002, unit='s', utc=True)` and `tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'); datetime.fromtimestamp(1554782410.0370002,tz=tz)`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to define in UTC (tz aware) then convert:

`pd.to_datetime(1554782410.0370002, unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert('US/Pacific')`

The obvious thing you *dont* want to do manually subtract hours.  If you happen to move, or your code runs on a server in another timezone, it will fail if you manually subtract off the hours.  In short: use a package/api for timezone management if you want timezone-aware times.

Answer (score 0):

Two options as I see it:

First is to manually subtract 7 hours using `pd.Timedelta()`:

```py
pd.to_datetime(1554782410.0370002, unit='s') - pd.Timedelta(hours=7)
```

Second would be to convert it to local time zone from UTC time using `tz_localize` and `tz_convert`. I think this method is slower, but does have the advantage of not worrying about calculating time difference manually or worrying about DST:

```py
pd.to_datetime(1554782410.0370002, unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles')
```